# Eclipse Java Search with multiple criteria

Tags: eclipse, search

I can search for a method returning a specific type or a method having a specific parameter type using the Eclipse Java Search tool.

But is there a way to search for a method returning a specific type (A.class) AND having a specific parameter type? (B.class)

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can specify both

```
java search 
-> search for -> type : 
-> limit to -> match locations -> return type & parameter type
```

[image: Java Search - search for - type]

[image: Match Location Selection - return type & parameter type]

Comment: While *Match locations* allow you to limit the matches to *Method return types* **or** *Method parameter types*, you cannot use this feature to search for methods with a return type of `A` **and** with parameters of a **different** type `B`.